# ffmpeg live stream only outputting 240p

Tags: ffmpeg

I am having trouble rescaling the resolution of a video with complex filters to 720p, adding the scale to reference the video seems to cause an error

```
ffmpeg -re -i "https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8" -i 
./public/images/ACE.png -i ./public/images/logo2.jpg -i 
./public/images/crunchy.png -i ./public/images/red.jpg -filter_complex "
[0]scale=1280:720[ovrl0], [va][ovrl0][v0];[1]scale=40:40[ovrl1], [v0]
[ovrl1] overlay=580:10:enable='lt(mod(t,40),10)'[v1];[2]scale=40:40[ovrl2], 
[v1][ovrl2] overlay=580:10:enable='between(mod(t,40),10,20)'[v2];
[3]scale=40:40[ovrl3], [v2][ovrl3] 
overlay=580:10:enable='gt(mod(t,40),20)'[v3];[4]scale=40:40[ovrl4], [v3]
[ovrl4] overlay=580:10:enable='gt(mod(t,40),30)'" -acodec aac -vcodec 
libx264 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/2222-2222-2222-2222"
```

error output is [AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f964163e9a0] No such filter: ''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filtergraph is malformed:

- `, [va][ovrl0][v0]` appears to be a typo and is not applied to any filter.
- Your first scale filter is referencing `[v0]` but `[v0]` does not exist (other than the orphaned declaration in the typo).
- `,` is use to join linear filters to create a filterchain. `;` is used to separate distinct filterchains. You're using `,` instead of `;` in some locations. See [FFmpeg Filter Syntax](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1).

I'm guessing you want something like:

```
-filter_complex \
"[0]scale=1280:720[ovrl0]; \
 [1]scale=40:40[ovrl1]; \
 [2]scale=40:40[ovrl2]; \
 [3]scale=40:40[ovrl3]; \
 [4]scale=40:40[ovrl4]; \
 [ovrl0][ovrl1] overlay=580:10:enable='lt(mod(t,40),10)'[v1]; \
 [v1][ovrl2] overlay=580:10:enable='between(mod(t,40),10,20)'[v2]; \
 [v2][ovrl3] overlay=580:10:enable='gt(mod(t,40),20)'[v3]; \
 [v3][ovrl4] overlay=580:10:enable='gt(mod(t,40),30)'"
```

Comment: Thats it but scaling the video to 720 p still outputs a very low quality image. I've read from your other answers I should use qscale:v but I haven't been able to figure out how to implement that onto the filtergraph

Comment: @Ricky I can't suggest very much without seeing the complete log from your command. `-qscale:v` is only for certain encoders (mjpeg, mpeg4, mpeg2video, mpeg1video, etc). Instead, for [streaming use `-b:v`, `-maxrate`, `-bufsize`, and `-g`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites). Also, avoid upscaling if possible.